# How to make search of words in several files via bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement, search, replace

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

text="hulk hogan,dolph ziggler"
IFS=","
word=( $text )

line=`ls workdir/*.txt`

for a in "${word[@]}"; do
for m in $line; do
if grep -q "$a" "$m"; then
    echo "$a word is exists"
    grep "$a" "$m"
else
    echo "$a word does not exists"
    exit 1
fi
done
done
```

It works, when I am trying to find `hulk hogan,dolph ziggler`, but only if these words exist in all files.

In case, where hulk hogan exists in the `first.txt` but not in the `second.txt` it will return an error.

Where is my mistake?

Help please.

I want to search these words in all files. In the case, if some word from array does not exist in all files, I want to get an error, but only in that case.

But if the word exists in one file, and the other word exists in another file, I want to get a positive result.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The problem is that `exit 1` when you can't find the word, then it will exit immediately. So just delete the line `exit 1`.

Comment: Couldn't you just `grep 'hulk hogan\|dolph ziggler' workdir/*.txt'` ?

Comment: guys, i need `exit 1`, because i don't want to start other parts of script, if i some word does not exists in all files. according to `grep 'hulk hogan\|dolph ziggler' workdir/*.txt'` no, because i need to do it in script, where i will use exceptions like if-else statements.

Comment: Specifically `[[ grep 'hulk hogan\|dolph ziggler' workdir/*.txt ]] && echo "word exists" || echo "word does not exist"`

Comment: As for your script with `if/else` and the looping. You currently loop through each file. If the search term is not found after your first search you exit. Don't exit. Perhaps save true/false to a variable, then after your loops test the variable to see if you found it or not. Exiting on your false condition doesn't make sense here.

Comment: i need to get `hulk hogan,dolph ziggler` in a array. because i will get them from input paramteres

Comment: Although you could just do `if [[ grep 'hulk hogan\|dolph ziggler' workdir/*.txt ]]; then ...` and then put the code you want to execute when this term exists.

Comment: @JNevill `if [[ grep .. ]]; then` seems wrong maybe you meant just `if grep ..; then` without quare brackets

Answer (score 0):

restore IFS after splitting text to avoid unexpected results

```
splitstr() {
    local ifs=$IFS
    IFS=$1 splitstr=( $2 ) IFS=$ifs
}

splitstr , "$text"
word=("${splitstr[@]}")
```

do not loop over ls output, use glob directly

```
for m in workdir/*.txt; do
```

to continue with the next entry of the innermost loop

```
continue
```

to continue with the next entry of the next enclosing loop

```
continue 2
```